# Simulation Model and For Loop in R

Tags: r, simulation

I am running a simulation model in R. How do I make the for loop multiply all capacity values and create a list of the average of each profit at the capacity level? Thank you!

```
BuildCost <- 16.00
SellPrice <- 3.70
VariableCost <- 0.20
OperationCost <- 0.40
Capacity <- c(30000,35000,40000,45000,50000,55000,60000)
Years <- 10

Profs <- c()
```

```
for (i in 1:1000){
  Demand <- rnorm(1,50000,12000)
  FixedCost <- Capacity*BuildCost
  AnnualProfit <- Demand * SellPrice
  ProductionCost <- Capacity*VariableCost
  OperationalCost <- Capacity*OperationCost
  TotalProfit <- Years*AnnualProfit-FixedCost-Years*(ProductionCost+OperationalCost)
  Profs[i]<- TotalProfit
  x <- mean(Profs[i])
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `replicate` to repeat the simulation for `n` times. `rowMeans` would calculate average of profit at each `Capacity`.

```
simulation <- function() {
  Demand <- rnorm(1,50000,12000)
  FixedCost <- Capacity*BuildCost
  AnnualProfit <- Demand * SellPrice
  ProductionCost <- Capacity*VariableCost
  OperationalCost <- Capacity*OperationCost
  Years*AnnualProfit-FixedCost-Years*(ProductionCost+OperationalCost)
}

rowMeans(replicate(100, simulation()))
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a results matrix with the right dimensions and populate it in the loop. The final result is exactly the same as the result of [Ronak Shah's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67945914/8245406) code if the RNG seed is set to the same value before the simulations are run.

```
set.seed(2021)
n <- 1000
Profs <- matrix(nrow = n, ncol = length(Capacity))
Demand <- rnorm(n, 50000, 12000)

for (i in seq_len(n)){
  FixedCost <- Capacity*BuildCost
  AnnualProfit <- Demand[i] * SellPrice
  ProductionCost <- Capacity*VariableCost
  OperationalCost <- Capacity*OperationCost
  TotalProfit <- Years*(AnnualProfit - ProductionCost - OperationalCost) - FixedCost
  Profs[i, ] <- TotalProfit
}

colMeans(Profs)
#[1] 1195661.9 1085661.9  975661.9  865661.9  755661.9  645661.9  535661.9
```